# Brotli compression didn't work as expected

Tags: asp.net, iis, brotli

Im having a weird problem with brotli compression on my iis 10 server.

for example some file getting passed with BR compression and some not.

this is my config on server :

1st ive installed this package and activate it with guide in it : [Microsoft IIS Compression (x64)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/iis-compression/iis-compression-overview)

2nd ive made this config in my **applicationHost.config** inside **C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config** : (commenting gzip section to force br)

```
 <httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
        <scheme name="br" dll="%ProgramFiles%\IIS\IIS Compression\iisbrotli.dll" />
        <!--<scheme name="gzip" dll="%ProgramFiles%\IIS\IIS Compression\iiszlib.dll" />-->
        <staticTypes>
            <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="application/atom+xml" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="application/xaml+xml" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="image/svg+xml" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
        </staticTypes>
    </httpCompression>
```

3rd ive add this file to my asp.net project web.config file :

```
<urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" dynamicCompressionBeforeCache="true" />
<httpCompression sendCacheHeaders="true" minFileSizeForComp="256" noCompressionForHttp10="false" noCompressionForProxies="false" noCompressionForRange="false" staticCompressionIgnoreHitFrequency="true" staticCompressionEnableCpuUsage="0" dynamicCompressionDisableCpuUsage="100" dynamicCompressionEnableCpuUsage="0" />
```

4th ive checked this folder for compressed br file :
**(C:\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files\Bonobo$^_br_D^\BONOBOPROJECT\CONTENT\DIST)**

[image]

5th when i test my **app.lib.min.js** file in browser it shows correct size : (BR size)
but some file passed with normal uncompressed size.

**Update** when i try with mutliple ip address in same time on files it passed the BR correct one.
how can i make iis to serve BR file all them time instead of waiting for multiple different IP request? ive set staticCompressionIgnoreHitFrequency to true based on this document [HTTP Compression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httpcompression/) but still it need multiple different hit to gives the BR version of file.

Comment: In your configuration you set `staticCompressionIgnoreHitFrequency="true"`. This should disable IIS's built-in behavior of tracking click frequency and choosing compression accordingly. But other compression settings may still affect behavior. Try setting `dynamicCompressionDisableCpuUsage` and `dynamicCompressionEnableCpuUsage` to 0 to ensure dynamic compression is always enabled.

Comment: ive change both setting but still nothing changed. full file served most of time.